# How to implement a dequeue function for a node-based priority queue?

Tags: python-3.x, nodes

A PQ where the `enqueue` method always adds an item to the end of the list, and the `dequeue` method searches the list for the highest-priority item and removes it from wherever it is. If you remove a node from the middle or end of the list, you will need to make sure to adjust the pointers to the nodes around it so the list doesn’t break.

```
  def dequeue(self):
        #searches the list for the highest-priority item and removes it from wherever it is
        if self._length > 0: #returns None if there is nothing in the queue
            
            temp=self._front
            temp2=self._front.get_next()

            while temp2!=self._rear: 
                if temp.get_data()>temp2.get_data(): #switch signs
                    temp=temp.get_next()
                    temp2=temp2.get_next()
                    #what do i need to do when it finds the highest priority item?????
            self._length-=1 #subtract one from the length
        return None
```

I know how to implement a regular linked queue, but I'm not sure what to do once it finds the highest priority item. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would do it by something like that:

```
 def dequeue(self):
    #searches the list for the highest-priority item and removes it from wherever it is
    if self._length > 0: #returns None if there is nothing in the queue
        
        best=self._front
        prev=None
        temp=self._front.get_next()

        while temp!=self._rear: 
            if temp.get_next().get_data()>best.get_data(): 
                best=temp.get_next() # set new best item
                prev=temp # set it's predecesor
            temp=temp.get_next()
        prev._next=best.get_next()  # I assume that '_next' is a name for field with reference to the next item, we want to replace it from best (which we will delete) to the next one
        self._length-=1 #subtract one from the length
        return best
    return None
```

Additionally I think it could be more clear and also easier to organise your queue while inserting elements instead of searching for the pritity much (but I understand that it is the matter of preference and specific case)

Comment: Hi in line 12 when I use "prev.get_next()=best.get_next()" I get an error because I can't use a function call there. Is there another way to reference the next item? Thank you!

Comment: It depends on the implementation, but if you keep reference to the next object in every object on your list, than you can just get that